# Tesseract failing on trivial input image. Segfault error

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm writing a tutorial on implementing a simple OCR web API in Flask using Tesseract. This has proven awesome so far, but I am currently running into a strange issue.

Here is what we are seeing:

`(Pdb) ENGINE.process_image(image)
*** TesseractError: (-11, 'index >= 0 && index < size_used_:Error:Assert failed:in file ../ccutil/genericvector.h, line 512')`

Now, I tried the following already. I believe it to be just a simple problem with the install...

Running tesseract -v gets me:

```
(codys_app)bobby@devbox:~/ocr/flask_server$ tesseract -v
tesseract 3.02.02
 leptonica-1.70
  libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.2.50 : libtiff 4.0.3 : zlib 1.2.8

```

I have tried uninstalling it and re-installing via apt-get, and re-building
it from source as well. I've had no luck.

My TESSDATA env var is `TESSDATA_PREFIX=/usr/local/share/`

Any ideas?
A post with the exact steps I've taken in setup and building this so far with complete
source code is available here
https://github.com/rhgraysonii/ocr_tutorial

Any help is more than appreciated. The goal here is to help others get into OCR
but I am sadly failing to get it to work properly.

Cheers! And thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Have you tried several different images of various file types and bit depths and stuff?  Basically anything you can do to see if it's Tesseract incorrectly barfing, or if it's a malformed file.  A lot of images aren't well formed but many image viewers can compensate by trying a few different tricks.  Tesseract may not try at all and just give up.